# Sublime Snippet, if no regex match use "null" string

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext-snippet

I'm trying to write a snippet. For this post I super simplified it. If I run it on this selection:

```
arg1
```

the snippet should output:

doFunc('arg1', 'null');

if I run it on this selection:

```
arg1, arg2
```

the snippet should output

doFunc('arg1', arg2);

I can't figure out how to use `null` string if no regex match is found. This is what I have so far:

```
 doFunc('${SELECTION/([^,]+)(,.*)?/\1/}', ${SELECTION/([^,]+)(,.*)?/\2/});
```

So the problem here is `${SELECTION/([^,]+)(,.*)?/\2/}` I want to do like a tertiary so like `\2 ? \2 : null` is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way of doing this in a snippet, as you can't perform computational logic in them aside from what the regexes do. You'll need a plugin for this.

Comment: Aw darn, thansk so much Matt for the reply :)

Comment: No problem. It's a feature that would be really nice to have, just simple `if..then..else` kind of logic, but we get what we get :)

Comment: At any rate, do you know Python? It shouldn't be too hard to put together a plugin that does this.

Comment: Thanks very much @MattDMo for the work arounds, I actually don't know python im a javascript guy, but ill look for some simple examples. I did read a bunch of python ctypes. By chance do you have any small python script that enables similar functionality? I learn best from taking a related piece of work and tweaking it :)

Comment: I'll see if I can come up with something.

Comment: My sincerest gratitude! +1 for the thought even if you dont get time to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text Snippets use the Boost library, which actually supports ternary operators in the [format part](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html). Hence you can just write `(?{2}(\2):'null')` like a ternary operator.

If you change your snippet to this it will have the specified behavior:

```
doFunc(${SELECTION/^([^,]+)(?:,\s*(.*))?/'\1', (?{2}(\2):'null')/});
```